# When configuring a Release Definition in VSTS to deploy a web site to Azure, can the Web Site Name be calculated at release time?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I'm setting up an automated deployment of a web site in VSTS to Azure using the "Azure Web App Deployment" task.  I have set up deployments in the past where the Web App Name was static for a particular target environment, but for this particular project, I'd like for the Web App Name to be calculated (in part) from a property determined at build time: the branch name, via the $(RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_CI_BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME) variable.  However, the Web App Name property of the "Azure Web App Deployment" task does not seem to expand server variables - it seems to expect and enforce a static value here.

I've also tried setting the -Name switch under Additional Parameters, but that seems to be overridden by the Web App Name I had to specify.

My question: is it possible to have the Web App Name calculated from server variables at the time of deployment, and if so, how is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_CI_BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME" is not a [Pre-defined variable](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/release//author-release-definition/understanding-tasks#predefvariables). So you cannot use it in tasks directly.

Following the steps below if you want use its value in Azure Web app deploy task:

1. Add a variable in your release definition, for example: "webappname".
2. Add a "PowerShell Script" task before "Azure Deployment" task, set "Type" to "Inline Script" and enter "Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=webappname;]$env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_LinkedBuildName_SOURCEBRANCHNAME"" in script content. This task will assign the source branch name of the build to "webappname" variable.
   [image]
3. Now you can use the variable "webappname" in the Azure Deployment task. Enter "$(webappname)" in "Web App Name" of the task.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try another task.  This one uses a WebDeploy package as well but allows for overriding MSSDeploy arguments:

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/03/22/vsts-release-custom-deploy-task-to-deploy-virtual-applications-to-azure/

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/04/20/msdeployallthethings-vststfs-extension-is-public/